# Indexed variable - Function that contains summation

Tags: functions, variable, index, indexed-variable

I have the following problem:
I have a function that looks like $f(c_1 , c_2 ) = c_1 + c_2 + c_3$.
The variables are $c_1$ and $c_2$, $c_3$ is a known constant. I would like to define a function
in mathematica that resembles this $f$ by telling the compiler that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are my variables, but $c_3$ is not! My first approach looked like this:

```
Subscript[c,3] = 2
f[Subscript[c,1],Subscript[c,2]] := Sum[Subscript[c,i],{i,1,3}]
```

However, as a test, `f[1,2]` does not return the number `5` as it should.

I have read other posts regarding this topic but have not understood them, because I am a complete beginner. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: 1. Don't use Subscript for computation; they are prone to weird behavior. Use indexed variables instead, like `c[1]`, `c[2]`. 2) You don't have to reproduce the notation if it makes your life harder; you could use `f[a_, b_] := a + b + c[3]`

Answer (score 1):

Input variables of functions in Mathematica should have `_` at the end of their names. Using `Subscript` in Mathematica is a little tricky and sometimes leads to unexpected results. It's recommended to not use them. Also, you can't use `_` in your variables, except in inputs of functions.

But for your problem, I will show some alternatives:

#### Solution 1

```
c3 = 2
f[c1_, c2_] := c1 + c2 + c3

f[1, 2]
(*Out: 5 *)
```

#### Solution 2

```
c3 = 2
f[c1_, c2_] := Sum[i, {i, {c1, c2, c3}}]

f[1, 2]
(*Out: 5 *)
```

#### Solution 3

If you'd defined your variables in `c1`, `c2` format:

```
c3 = 2;
f[c1_, c2_] := Evaluate[Sum[Symbol["c" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 3}]]

f[1, 2]
(*Out: 5 *)
```

This solution will use `Symbol` to automatically access variables by building their names as string.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and quick answer! I missed a very important point: The function I stated above is more a trivial function in order to ask the question more easily. The actual function I am dealing with involves an arbitrary amount of c_k, where c1 and c2 are my variables and all remaining c_k are constants. Also, they are not just summed over with plusses as my function above, but are computed in a more complex way. So is there a general way do define a function with subscript variables, where I tell the compiler that only two specific of them are actual variables?

Comment: @MegAmaNeo1 As far as I know, inputs of function should be symbol without any wrapper like `Subscript`. for your problem, I added `solution 3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I recommend that you avoid the use of subscripted variables and instead use indexed variables. You can display the indexed variables in any desired manner using [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html).

```
Format[c[n_]] := Subscript[c, n]

n = 5;

var = Array[c, n]
```

[image]

To set variables `c[3]` through `c[n]` equal to a constant

```
Set[c[#], k] & /@ Range[3, n];
```

Then

```
var
```

[image]

To use the variables as arguments to a function

```
f @@ var
```

[image]

```
Total@var
```

[image]

```
Sum[c[m]/m!, {m, 1, n}]
```

[image]